# Advantage of using DialogResult.Cancel

Tags: c#, winforms

What would the advantage of using:

```
DialogResult.Cancel
```

Over using:

```
this.Close()
```

Would it be just so that you would be able to determine that the user has selected `Cancel`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it value for this kind of purpose

```
var result = form.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK) 
{

}
else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel) 
{
  //perform soem operation
}
```

So if you want to perform some operation on the result of dialog you can use this.

Note :

Both of this ok and cancel operation on dialog close your dialog, and by catching ok and cancel value you can perform extra task as given in above example.

Answer (score 4):

Those consuming your interface, if showing the form with `ShowDialog`, would get a result. They would *know* the user pressed `Cancel`.

As an aside. You can set the `Form` properties `AcceptButton` and `CancelButton`. Then, if the form is shown with `ShowDialog`, when they are clicked the base `Form` will set the `DialogResult` and thus the `Form` will close on its own.